# Heroku Application Error when Viewing Dash App in broswer

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, plotly-dash

I am attempting to deploy my dash app built using Python on heroku. The manual deploy by connecting to my [Github repo branch](https://github.com/zachcornelison/memphis-zip-code-app-deployment) works fine and says it deployed successfully, but when I visit the page I get the error message

"Application error.
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
'heroku logs --tail'"

My dashboard runs fine when deploying locally.

Comment: Your app seems to require some input data ('zipcode-data.csv') but I don't see a 'data' folder in your GitHub repo. As stated in the error message reported in your question you could also print the logs (with the command 'heroku logs') to check in more detail what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Dash is built on top of Flask, so I believe you need to configure the port when deploying on Heroku

```
app.run(debug=True, port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)), host='0.0.0.0')
```

The port is provided (dynamically) by Heroku with the $PORT env variable, in the example the default 5000 is used when the env variable is undefined (ie locally)

Comment: The comment above actually solved the problem, I was just missing the data file on my github. Thank you though!

Comment: Great it works, please accept the answer (might help others too)